# Однократное выполнение условия в python

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется двухуровневый массив со ссылками на фото.

Имеется переменная item = 0

Имеется функция «следующий товар», которая при нажатии отправляет в бот фото и плюсует счётчик item += 1

Имеется функция «предыдущий товар», которая при нажатии вычитает один счётчик item -= 1

Получается, что всё вроде бы работает нормально, но! Поскольку доступ к элементам массива начинается с нуля, то индекс содержимого массива всегда меньше на 1 чем переменная item после выполнения функции след. товар.

Выходит если нажать на след. товар, а потом на пред. товар, то мы увидим два раза один и тот же товар.

Значит при первом нажатии кнопки пред. товар функция однократно должна вычитать 2 единицы из item.

А как это сделать ума не приложу. Подскажите новичку.

Comment: Может вы все таки приложите код?

Comment: 'Выходит если нажать на след. товар, а потом на пред. товар, то мы увидим два раза один и тот же товар." А можно зто увидеть в виде кода?